# When copying a sheet into another Google Sheets file, how to keep comments?

Tags: google-sheets

Does this only work on specific OSes?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot copy and paste a cell with the attached comments but you can **cut and paste** a cell.

Answer (score 2):

you are probably seeking a method which will allow you to copy a cell(s) containing a comment(s) and paste such cell(s) in a way to keep those comments. unfortunately, such a method doesn't exist.

the only way to copy comments from a given sheet is to make a global copy of such sheet:

- go to **File**
- select **Make a copy...**
- choose **Copy comments**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also went to this page to get some answers. After seeing that there is no instant way to do it, this is what I did

1. Download Google sheet files as Excel (the comments will be included in the download)
2. Make one consolidated Excel file for the worksheets that you want to consolidate (right-click the Tab, Move or Copy (select your new consolidated file)
3. Upload the file to Google Drive
4. Open file as Google Sheet
5. File>Save as Google Sheet

Comment: Works similarly for docs too, Word lets you merge specific elements, like taking just the comments from several files into a master edit.

Answer (score 0):

From [Create, view, or save a file](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/49114?hl=en) (pay attention to step 4)

> **COMPUTER**
>
> **Make a copy of a file**
>
> 1. On your computer, open a Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, or Forms home screen.
>    Open the file you want to make a copy of.
> 2. In the menu, click File and then Make a copy.
> 3. Type a name and choose where to save it.
> 4. If you want to copy comments from a document, spreadsheet, or presentation, click Copy comments and suggestions or Copy comments.
> 5. Click Ok.

The Android/ iOS apps doesn't include the option to Copy comments and suggestions / Copy comments

Comment: need confirmation that there's no other ways to do this?

 like you cant copy/paste? or right click on a tab/sheet > 'copy to' ?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands you can't even paste with comments within the same sheet. However, within the same sheet you can, with a little ingenuity, move a section of cells around without losing the comments. The Insert-Cells/Shift and Delete-Cells/Shift options (available by right clicking on a cell or some selected cells) can be used to move a set of cells around on a sheet with the comments intact.

Not the solution to the original problem, but I got here when I searched for the solution to this problem (which I then solved myself), so I figured someone else might too.